# Word to describe a time interval

Tags: single-word-requests

When a magazine subscription is about to expire the publisher sends a notification to the subscriber. The notification is usually sent a month before expiration, however this value varies based on the subscriber profile. Is there an English word to describe this value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not a *single* word but the term **notice period** comes to mind:

> [[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/notice-period)]
>   **notice period** (noun)
>   - the period between the time that you are told about something and the time that it must happen or be done

Answer (score 5):

### Renewal Notice  -or-  Renewal Period

Another option not a single word, but it may fit better specifically with subscriptions.

> **renewal**
>   [Miriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renewal)
>
> renewal noun
>
> Definition of renewal
>
> 3 : something (such as a subscription to a magazine) renewed

In some cases this before your subscription expires and sometimes it is where they send you "just one more" periodical, extending the contract beyond what you originally paid.

> **renewal**     [The free dictionary](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/renewal)
>
> n. keeping an existing arrangement in force for an additional period of time, such as a lease, a promissory note, insurance policy or any other contract. Renewal usually requires a writing or some action which evidences the new term.

Answer (score 3):

Coming from a more technical background, one could refer to the **Notification Window**, where the term "window" is used as indicated in this meaning from the [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/window):

> 5. An interval of time during which an activity can or must take place: 
>      *a window of opportunity for a space mission;* 
>      *a window of vulnerability when the air force was subject to attack.*

Answer (score 2):

Also an expression and not a single word:

> **[time limit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/time_limit)**
>
> A limit of time within which something must be done.